# AWS Firehose API Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm looking to use a fixed version of the AWS Kinesis Firehose API instead of using just "latest" for the version, where might I find a list of the API versions for AWS Kinesis Firehose?

```
return new FirehoseClient([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'us-west-2',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => "fake2",
            'secret' => "fake1"
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version is `2015-08-04`.

This can be found <strike>at the top of any page in the [Kinesis Firehose API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).  The same is true for most AWS services.</strike> in the PDF version of the API reference documentation, which is linked at the top of each page of the HTML documentation.  For some reason, the API version no longer appears in the HTML versions of the docs.

Comment: Thanks a ton that was hiding in plain sight. To me that just looked like the date for the API documentation.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I can't find it. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @pir thanks for mentioning that.  They changed this.  I've updated the answer accordingly.  `2015-08-04` is still correct.  API version changes are fairly uncommon on most AWS services, since they don't tend to bump it when adding new functionality that has no overlap with existing functionality, meaning old clients can still do what they were always able to do.